# need to know how do I pass JavaScript variables to PHP using html form or cookie or even any other way?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to know how to pass variable output of JavaScript to PHP variable for the following code. Saw some code that suggests using a html form or cookie, but didn't know how to apply it to my code.

```
.then(function(response){
                      //Log full response
                      //console.log(response.data.results[0].address_components[6].short_name);
                        console.log(response);

                      //Formatted Address
                        var formattedAddress = response.data.results[0].formatted_address;
                        var formattedAddressOutput = `
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">${formattedAddress}</li>
                        </ul>
                        `;

                        //address Components 
                        var addressComponents = response.data.results[0].address_components;
                        var addressComponentsOutput = '<ul class="list-group">';
                        for(var i = 0; i < addressComponents.length;i++)
                        {
                            addressComponentsOutput += `
                                <li 
                                class="list-group-item"><strong>${addressComponents[i].types[0]}</strong>: ${addressComponents[i].long_name}</li>   
                            `;
                        }
                        addressComponentsOutput += '</ul>';

                      //Output to app
                      document.getElementById('formatted-address').innerHTML = formattedAddressOutput;
                      //document.getElementById('address-components').innerHTML = addressComponentsOutput;



                    })

                    .catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });


                }


        </script>
```

Comment: _“but didn't know how to apply it to my code”_ - I wouldn’t know either in this instance … Please don’t just throw such a piece of code at us without _any_ explanation of what you are doing there in the first place. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: To send something to the server you need to make a HTTP request. From the browser the usual ways to do that are clicking on a link, submitting a form, or making an AJAX request via JavaScript. You need to decide which one you need and then look up how to implement it. If you get stuck with implementation then ask us again